# Remove notification count when swiped away in drawer

Tags: android, notifications

I have a Galaxy S5 running 4.4.2 rooted.

When I swipe away a notification form my notification drawer is there anyway I can make it also consider the notification as seen / read (or to give me the choice of whether to mark it as seen or not) so that I don't have to go into messages or calls or whatever and 'see' it again?

Comment: In what prospective are you asking this? As a developer, to handle this programmatically in your application or a rootted device user, who wants to do it for some apps downloaded in mobile.

Comment: As a user for samsungs default messaging and calling apps